# How to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n\cos(k\pi)\binom{n}{k}=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\cos(k\pi)\binom{n}{k}=0$$

I approached this problem having no idea that $\cos(k\pi)$ could be substituted so easily.
I tried first to expand the sum to $n$. So I wanted to ask if anyone knows how to expand this kind of sum? Would highly appreciate it. Is it like $1\times\cos(k\pi)$ and expand $(1+\cos(k\pi))^n$?

Comment: Hint: for $k\in\Bbb Z$ the expression $\cos(k\pi)$ is $(-1)^k$ in disguise. Also the identity fails for $n=0$.

Comment: Thanks a Ton man! nice ppl here!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that $\cos k\pi=(-1)^k$, so you are asking for
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(1)^{n-k}(-1)^k$$
$$=(1+-1)^n=0^n=0$$
The removal of the sigma comes from the binomial theorem.

**ADDED:** As Marc van Leeuwen pointed out in a comment, the identity fails for $n=0$. This is because $0^n$ is *not* zero for $n=0$. Nice catch, Marc!

Comment: omg! thnks so much man kudos and god bless ya!

Comment: hello Sir would like to know the removal of sigma a bit. I have no idea how it reached from 2nd last to the last step.

Comment: @Sash: The binomial theorem says $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}a^{n-k}b^k$. That step used $a=1$ and $b=-1$. (I just edited it a bit to make it more clear.)

Comment: got it thnks again.

Answer (score 14):

The desired sum is the real part of

$$\sum_{k=0}^n e^{ik\pi}{n\choose k}=(1+e^{i\pi})^n=0$$